# Return Arrays From Method as a Parameter

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

```
public static void find( int[] numbers) {
    int[] range = new int[5];
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) 
    {
        if(numbers[i]>=10 && numbers[i] <= 20) 
        {
            range[i]=range[i]+numbers[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a method that find the numbers between 10 and 20 in a array and assign them to another array. [this is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDhpv.png) and this is what I got.
`{ 0 0 0 }  are between 10 - 20`  how can I fix this ?

```
public static void read( int[] numbers) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for( int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++)
    {   
        System.out.print("Number["+i+"] => ");
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    input.close();
}
```

This is the read() method that reads numbers from user and assign to an array.

```
public static void print( int[] numbers, int[]range) {
    
    System.out.println("Number = { "+ numbers[0]+" "+numbers[1]+" "+numbers[2]+" "+numbers[3]+" "+numbers[4]+" }");
    System.out.println("{ "+range[0]+" "+range[1]+" "+range[2]+" } "+" are between 10 - 20 ");
}
```

And this is the print(x,y) method that prints the numbers and range arrays.

My main method is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    read( numbers );
    int[] range = new int[5];
    find( numbers );
    print(numbers, range);
```

The numbers array must include 3 numbers between 10-20.

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Post them as code along with your post.

Comment: don't use for range the same running variable as for numbers

Comment: If you want your method to return anything it needs a return type different than `void`. Your method currently does not return any object at all. So I'm not sure how you even run it to get the output you posted.

Comment: I have 2 more methods. One reads array from user , other one is writes the array and range array.

Comment: @crawlmontana then share this with us

Comment: Im sorry. Im newbie in here. And my english is not well. Im edited my post and i will share my code.

Comment: If you want the array returned, then you should return it: ``public static int[] read() { ... }`` Please don't rely on side-effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

- Change the return type of your function to int[]
- precalculate the size of your ranges array with counter
- store the values which are in your range in the range array
- return the range array

**Note** dont use the i running variable also for your range array, if you do so when not every value is in your range the result array will have gaps meaning values with the value of zero.

In the read function you should return the readed-in values to use it then in your find function

```
public static int[] read(int size) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[size];
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {   
        System.out.print("Number["+(i+1)+"] => ");
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        // to remove the new line character
        input.nextLine();
    }
    input.close();
    return numbers;
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] values = MyClass.read(10);
        int[] result = MyClass.find(values);
        // result is now the return value of the find method
        // you can parse it now to another method of your choice
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

    }


    public static int[] find(int[] numbers) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] >= 10 && numbers[i] <= 20) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        int[] range = new int[counter];


        int counter2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] >= 10 && numbers[i] <= 20) {
                range[counter2] = numbers[i];
                counter2++;
            }

        }
        return range;

    }
    public static int[] read(int size) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print("Number[" + (i+1) + "] => ");
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
            // to remove the new line character
            input.nextLine();
        }
        input.close();
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You need to return the 'range' array in the 'find' function because otherwise, it isn't accessible.

**2.** You need another variable say 'j' to point to the indices of the 'range' array.
The same variable can't be used for both the 'numbers' array and the 'range' array.

**3.** It will be better to pass the size of the 'numbers' array through the 'read' function and then read the array using the 'read' function.

**Functions:**
find() function:

```
 public static int[] find( int[] numbers) {
    int[] range = new int[5];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) 
    {
        if(numbers[i]>=10 && numbers[i] <= 20) 
        {
            range[j]=range[j]+numbers[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return range;
}
```

read() function:

```
public static int[] read( int n) {
    int[] numbers = new int[n];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for( int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++)
    {   
        System.out.print("Number["+i+"] => ");
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    input.close();
    return numbers;
}
```

print() function[Remains same]:

```
public static void print( int[] numbers, int[]range) {
    
    System.out.println("Number = { "+ numbers[0]+" "+numbers[1]+" "+numbers[2]+" "+numbers[3]+" "+numbers[4]+" }");
    System.out.println("{ "+range[0]+" "+range[1]+" "+range[2]+" } "+" are between 10 - 20 ");
}
```

Main function accordingly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int[] numbers = read(n);
    int[] range = find(numbers);
    change(numbers);
    print(numbers, range);
}
```